# What conditions to publish my app in playstore which uses glide

Tags: android

I created an app which internally uses glide(https://github.com/bumptech/glide).
But I am not sure what conditions I need to follow to publish it to the play store like should I have to provide glide licence link in about of my app or should I mention the glide licence in any other place?

Comment: do you mean you are using glide for image loading purpose??

Comment: Caveat: I am not a lawyer... Usually the link/text of the license would just get put in some obscure menu in your app settings. For example, in the Chrome app you can find it by going to "Settings ->About Chrome -> Legal information -> Open source licenses", which currently has both "Glide" and a broken link for "glide"... If your app has a web site you could link it there too.

Comment: "do you mean you are using glide for image loading purpose??" yes